# Are there very large format POD publishers?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, print-on-demand

I have a low quantity book project that will need a book sized A3 with 1000-1500 pages. Is there a print on demand provider out there that could possibly handle that?

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you're after, but is it possible to perhaps go through the Amazon KDP to print it yourself?

Comment: Not sure, but it doesn't look like A3 is a format on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They exist.  Though it depends where you are.

A3 appears to be art book sized.

> The A3 size print measures 29.7 x 42.0cm, 11.69 x 16.53 inches, if
>   mounted 40.6 x 50.8cm, 15.98 x 20 inches. ([ref](https://www.stephenwiltshire.co.uk/paper_sizes.aspx))

Why does it talk about mounting?  Because it's a designation for art prints, not books.

> A3 is a paper size that is typically used for drawings, diagrams and
>   large tables. It is also frequently used in laser printers to output
>   two A4 pages as a spread....A3 measures 297 × 420 millimeters or 11.69 × 16.54 inches.
>   In PostScript, its dimensions are rounded off to 842 × 1190 points...
>
> In the American market ISO paper sizes are hardly used at all. The
>   US-alternative to A3 is called Tabloid or Ledger (ANSI B) and measures
>   11 x 17″ or 279 × 432 mm. ([ref](https://www.prepressure.com/library/paper-size/din-a3))

I did a Google search and quickly found several [print-on-demand companies](https://www.bookbaby.com/art-book-printing) that handles art books, which should be in the correct size range. ([Another one](http://www.editiononebooks.com/))

So why A3?  Will 11x17" do?  Are you outside of the US in a place where A3 is commonly used for books?

As for the page count of your book, that's going to be really heavy.  Especially if you're using quality paper which is heavier.  And then there is the larger dimensions.  Will anyone be able to lift your book?  Perhaps you want multiple volumes?

Comment: I am outside the US, and it's sort of an art project based around writing. Neither site you linked seemed to offer a comparable iption?

Comment: This is a good illustration (pun intended) of why it's important to give your location in your question.  The sites I found are not ones I've heard of or used but ones that do POD art books in the general size you're looking for, but in the US.  It does look, however, that you'll need to find a *book* format that is close to A3, vs getting A3 itself.

Comment: Okay, you're in Denmark.  So you need a publisher in north western Europe, if not the actual country of Denmark.  Depending on where you want them to ship to.  With POD, where you are is a lot less important than where your customers are.

Comment: A format close to A3 might be fine, but I still can't find any.

Comment: Have you contacted CPI? http://cpibooks.com/  Their website isn't cooperating so I can't get size info, but you can just phone or email them.  They don't print in Denmark but they do nearby Western European countries.

Comment: KDP Print prints in Europe (and is now merged with CreateSpace, which works with Amazon).  https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/GSJULX3WGP36HQ3R  But they appear to only go up to 297mm height/width.  https://www.amazon.co.uk/b/ref=BKLN85/262-7668637-8749564?ie=UTF8&node=9641673031&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-leftnav&pf_rd_r=126B7JNXB3ZS40ATSKNF&pf_rd_r=126B7JNXB3ZS40ATSKNF&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=4c2f4639-dc7b-42b8-a37b-c2ba8032117f&pf_rd_p=4c2f4639-dc7b-42b8-a37b-c2ba8032117f&pf_rd_i=9534081031

Comment: Completely Novel prints on demand in Europe but only goes up to 189 mm x 246mm (7.44″ × 9.69″).
https://www.completelynovel.com/self-publishing/price-calculator

Comment: PrintNinja is an American-owned company doing printing in China and ships all over the world.  Anything up to 17" is a standard size to them!  (over 17" is custom work).  https://www.printninja.com/printing-products also https://www.printninja.com/printing-resource-center/printing-options/book-services/size

Comment: I can't find their book sizes but here's another European printer.  May not be on-demand though.  https://europeanprinter.com/

Answer (score 1):

*Better late than never...*

The realistic answer to your question is **NO**. Tabloid / A3 is much larger than reasonably priced POD houses can handle.  You might have to try a company that specialises in large books, like [atlases](http://www.riesgraphics.com/Services/atlasMapPrinting).

Alternatively, you can go down the Do It Yourself route.  Most local printshops (in the US, Staples, Office Depot or UPS Store) can handle tabloid sized paper.  I'm sure their counterparts in Europe can handle A3. If you don't want to drill a/o punch holes in the paper yourself, just have them use pre-punched paper. You might even be able to get them to use your own paper, so long as it's compatible with laser printers.

I recently finished an "art project based around writing" myself, a work of fantasy geopoesy. No POD book makers can handle tabloid, so it was off to the UPS Store for me!

Once they printed it, it was just a matter of binding & making a cover. I use a modified Oriental binding stitch for the pages, and cloth tapes to attach the book boards and glue for the end papers & leather cover.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some can do A3 size.

Unaware of any that can do 1000-1500 pages.  Even real publishers do not normally do that.

Your best bet is to cut it to smaller volumes.

Or you could print but not bind the pages with many book printers or copy shops and then take them for binding to a bindery that could do a book that big.

But you seriously need to rethink the need for even having a book with that many pages at that size.

Those links someone gave above show a 12x12 maximum,  and the other one had a page limit. Each may have other restrictions.

Your book is overspecified and you must compromise to make it feasible.